# What is difference between max sdk version and target sdk version?

Tags: android-manifest, android-sdk-tools

I have little confusion about max sdk version and target sdk version.is it any problem if i am using these two in my manifest.xml file

Answer (score 8):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html:

### android:maxSdkVersion

> An integer designating the maximum API Level on which the application
>   is designed to run.
>
> In Android 1.5, 1.6, 2.0, and 2.0.1, the system checks the value of
>   this attribute when installing an application and when re-validating
>   the application after a system update. In either case, if the
>   application's maxSdkVersion attribute is lower than the API Level used
>   by the system itself, then the system will not allow the application
>   to be installed. In the case of re-validation after system update,
>   this effectively removes your application from the device.

### android:targetSdkVersion

> An integer designating the API Level that the application targets. If
>   not set, the default value equals that given to minSdkVersion. This
>   attribute informs the system that you have tested against the target
>   version and the system should not enable any compatibility behaviors
>   to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version.
>   The application is still able to run on older versions (down to
>   minSdkVersion).

## Versioning your application

If you want to have more details about these 2 parameters and how they affect your application, I think **[this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html)** will help you to have a better understanding on the subject:

- **android:minSdkVersion** — The minimum version of the Android platform on which the application will run, specified by the platform's API Level identifier.
- **android:targetSdkVersion** — Specifies the API Level on which the application is designed to run. In some cases, this allows the application to use manifest elements or behaviors defined in the target API Level, rather than being restricted to using only those defined for the minimum API Level.
- **android:maxSdkVersion** — The maximum version of the Android platform on which the application is designed to run, specified by the platform's API Level identifier. Important: Please read the  documentation before using this attribute.

Comment: Can we upload two application using maxSdkVersion. So that we can have one application <= max sdk version and other application (> max sdk version in first)

Answer (score -3):

Max version it is the maximum version that can be used.
Target version it is version for that app is target to.