# Should I use "android.maxSdkVersion" in the manifest.xml file?

Tags: android

Should I use `android.maxSdkVersion` in `manifest.xml` file? Because I read in documents that I should not use this in `manifest.xml` file. And as regards most version of android devices are 2.3 to higher. What is your opinion?

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/24244887/what-is-difference-between-max-sdk-version-and-target-sdk-version

Comment: When are you going to accept an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Google stated at Android Developers:

> **Warning**: Declaring this attribute is **not recommended**. First, there is no need to set the attribute as means of **blocking deployment of your application onto new versions** of the Android platform as they are released. By design, new versions of the platform are **fully backward-compatible**. Your application should **work properly on new versions**, provided it uses only standard APIs and follows development best practices. Second, note that in some cases, declaring the attribute can result in your application **being removed from users' devices after a system update** to a higher API Level. Most devices on which your application is likely to be installed will receive periodic system updates over the air, so you should consider their effect on your application before setting this attribute.

Syntax:

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="integer"
    android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
    android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

However if you use the new `Gradle` then `android:minSdkVersion="integer"` and `android:targetSdkVersion="integer"` will always be overridden in the `Gradle` scripts.

I suggest you not to use it.

Here is a guide for more detailed information:

[Android Developers - uses-sdk-element in manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Comment: The quoted text is a lie. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files There is nothing "backward-compatible" with the new restrictions of Android 13. I should support devices back to Android 8. "To support media file access on devices that run Android 9 (API level 28) or lower, declare the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission and set the maxSdkVersion to 28."